# My PC does not sleep, hibernate, or shutdown properly

Tags: windows-10, sleep, shutdown, hibernate

I´ve been struggling with this problem for a while now, when I command my computer to shutdown, sleep or hibernate it does not. I´ve tried: Updating windows, updating drivers, changing power plans. All failures.

Now I will show my event log, I do not fully understand it, so if anyone could help me find the problem I will appreciate that. I put it upside down for clarity.

LOGS:

> Information 1/03/2019 8:00:46 a. m.   Kernel-Power    187 (243)
>
> The user mode process attempted to change the state of the system by
>   calling the SetSuspendState or SetSystemPowerState APIs.
>
> Information 1/03/2019 8:00:52 a. m.   Kernel-Power    42  (64)
>
> The system is going into suspension. Reason for suspension:
>   Application API
>
> Information 1/03/2019 8:00:54 a. m.   Kernel-Power    107 (102)
>
> The system resumed from the suspended state.
>
> Error 1/03/2019 8:00:54 a. m. Kernel-Power    137 None
>
> The system firmware changed the registers of the processor memory type
>   range (MTRR) during a suspension state transition (S5). This can
>   reduce the performance of the resume.

I believe the last error is when I force shutdown my PC, basically I select hibernation and then when the PC does not reduce the power (only monitor is turn off) I force shutdown, in this way I am able to pick it up how I left it. Any question or if you required more information just let me know.

OS: Win10 pro 1809
Mobo: Asrock H310

Comment: Is it able to reboot without issue, or is it the same thing with that too?

Comment: May I ask, how can I get these logs...?

Comment: Try this command: `shutdown -s -t 0 -f`

Comment: Hi, yes I can reboot, but is a weird reboot, the PC turns off for about 3 sec before turning on again. The logs can be found in the event viewer, just typing Event in the start. 
Yes, I also tried the force shutdown with that command, did not worked.

Comment: Have you checked the BIOS for whether S3 is enabled?

Comment: I have not, I will learn how to do it and come back to you

Comment: The settings I saw where: Deep Sleep: Disabled, Suspend to RAM: AUTO (The description reads: It is recommended to select auto for ACPI S3 power saving).

And there was a setting that reads: Intel(R) Platform Trsut technology: Disabled, this setting has any impact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was fixed by accident. I upgraded my RAM, so I unplogged the computer, when I hibernate it again it did it succesfully, so whatever is was, was not stopped by forcing shutdown, but when unplogged. Thanks for your answers, I hope this works for anyone else with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed for me.

I was experiencing the same problem (also running an ASRock MB, interestingly). I tried the command `shutdown -s -t 0 -f` , which shut down my PC. I left it overnight and after rebooting, my PC will now sleep normally.

Comment: Hi, I tried that again, but it was the same, the computer appeared to shutdown yet the lights, fants, etc where still on. Then after rebooting I tried to use sleep with no success.